# How to read multiple lines with breaks in a Function?

Tags: python, spyder

I wanted to know how to read multiple lines in a function and then run it. For example I am reading  this path what should I put in the end of my second line so that it reads ',sheet_name='Live Promos' and run properly.

```
Live_Promo=pd.read_excel("""C:\\Users\\BF68499\\_Inc\\Documents\\\
                         KT\\Pro\\92-2l D_TS.xlsx"""
                         ,sheet_name='Live Promos')
#Output
#FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

When I keep it in single line like this it reads it fine.

```
Live_Promo=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\BF64899\\_Inc\\Documents\\KT\\Pro\\92-2l D_TS.xlsx",sheet_name='Live Promos')
#Output
#reads file fine
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `str` (emphasis mine):

> Triple quoted strings may span multiple lines - **all associated whitespace will be included in the string literal**.

Example:

```
In [5]: print("""C:\\Users\\BF68499\\_Inc\\Documents\\\
   ...:                          KT\\Pro\\92-2l D_TS.xlsx""")
C:\Users\BF68499\_Inc\Documents\                         KT\Pro\92-2l D_TS.xlsx
```

This is probably not what you intended...

You can use a backslack between strings on multiple lines. That will lead to the strings being combined:

```
In [3]: print("foo"\
   ...: "bar")
foobar
```

Alternatively, you can put multiple strings in an expression with only whitespace between them:

```
In [4]: print(("spam " "eggs"))
spam eggs
```

You can also use a string `join`:

```
long_list = [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
    "string4",
    "string5",
]
really_long_string = ''.join(long_list)
```

Comment: @Damandeep I've added an example.

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for thank you. One more thing popped in my head. What if I have a query with 1000 lines. I can't go each line and put quotes then back slash. How do we read it then? You can take example of five lines.

Comment: @Damandeep Try a string join. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 '\' after Documents in your path. There should be only 2.